# NHibernate, MultiThreading and Shared Object Update Conflict

Tags: c#, multithreading, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I understand that ISession is not thread safe and SessionFactory is thread safe.  As such, I've wrapped and confirmed that I have one session per thread.

I'm receiving an error under the following situation and was wondering if this is something not supported, or I'm still missing something with my ISession thread isolation.

I am running NUnit tests.  I have a scenario where my Entity is stubbed out as a field variable.  I have a test that runs 2 parallel tasks.

• Each parallel task creates its own session from the same SessionFactory and begins an NHibernate Transaction.
• They each update the entity and perform a SaveOrUpdate on it.
• Then Commit and close the transaction.
Each task does this about 10k times.

During this test I get a message:

```
System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred.
  ----> NHibernate.HibernateException : identifier of an instance of Domain.Entity.MyEntity was altered from 2 to 1
```

This makes sense because the MyEntity is a field object and consumed by both threads.  So a single object created in the NUnit class is reference and updated by both threads.

My question is whether a scenario like this can be avoided by pessimistic locking or other NHibernate features?  Or is this just not do-able and I have to make sure this situation (i.e my Entity object is not referenced and updated by more than one thread at a time) never occurs in my code?

I've tired some options in NHibernate, like ensuring versioning of the entity and tried some locking calls, but I'm guessing in the dark through the documentation which is the right way, if any to handle this scenario.

Edit:  Thanks for the comments!  Here is the code in the unit test:

```
private PluginConfiguration _configStub1;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        new FluentMapper().Configuration().ExposeConfiguration(
            e => new SchemaExport(e).Drop(false, true)
            );

        _configStub1 = new PluginConfiguration()
            {
                Enabled = true,
                Keys = "Name",
                Value = "Fred",
                PluginName = "red",
                RuntimeId = 1
            };
     }

    [Test]
    [Explicit]
    public void HighVolume_Saves_MultiManager_SameDataRecord_SameInstance_MultiThread()
    {
        Action action1 = () =>
        {
            var dal = new DataAccessManager();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                dal.Begin();
                dal.Current.Session.SaveOrUpdate(_configStub1);
                dal.Current.Commit();
                dal.End();
            }
        };

        Action action2 = () =>
        {
            var dal = new DataAccessManager();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                dal.Begin();
                dal.Current.Session.SaveOrUpdate(_configStub1);
                dal.Current.Commit();
                dal.End();
            }
        };

        var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(action1);
        var task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(action2);

        task1.Wait();
        task2.Wait();
    }
```

The DataAccess Manager referenced in the test is as follows:

```
public class DataAccessManager : IDataAccessManager
{
    private readonly ThreadLocal<ISessionManager> _current = new ThreadLocal<ISessionManager>();

    public void Begin()
    {
        Current = new SessionManager();
    }
    public ISessionManager Current
    {
        get { return _current.Value; }
        set { _current.Value = value; }
    }
    public void End(bool doComplete = true)
    {
        bool isActive = Current.Transaction != null && Current.Transaction.IsActive;

        if (doComplete && isActive) Current.Commit();
        else if (!doComplete && isActive) Current.Transaction.Rollback();

        Current.Dispose();
    }
}
```

The SessionManager is as such:

```
public class SessionManager : ISessionManager
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="SessionManager"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public SessionManager()
    {
        Session = ContextFactory.OpenSession();
        Transaction = Session.BeginTransaction();
    }

    public ITransaction Transaction { get; private set; }
    public ISession Session { get; private set; }

    public void Commit()
    {
        try
        {
            Transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Transaction.Rollback();
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the retrieving of your object included in the transaction (I always thought this kind of conflict problem should not occur then) ? or do you start your transaction after retrieving your object ?

Comment: Can you post some code please? I do not exactly understand what you mean by "stubbed out as a field variable". In any case, if your mapping has an automatically managed Id - you can't assign the Id property.

Comment: @jbl, no, it is a new object with a SaveOrUpdate call.

Comment: I was wondering if the problem could come from the fact that you are passing the same object reference 2000 times to SaveorUpdate in different threads and different sessions. Does it correspond to a real use case scenario ? Have you tried passing a brand new object to your SaveOrUpdate on each SaveOrUpdate call ?

Comment: @jbl I'm very certain this is the case as you mention - single object reference into multiple threads.  I do have another test that passes a new object instance per thread, and that passes fine.  The use case scenario is theoretical at this point.  Since we're using TDD I only got as far as the test, so if this can't be handled by NHibernate's ISession, then I'll have to figure a different design.

Comment: maybe you can try evicting the object after the commit. Not sure it would lead somewhere. And it should need some refactoring, as I can't see a place for it in the existing code

Comment: @jbl  I've tried to update with an evict.  But, same error.  Good thought though.

Comment: BTW : If you want to achieve thread safety, why don't you lock your object ? Combined to evict, it should ensure thread safety and consistency

Comment: @jbl - that did it!  I tried locking before posting to SO, but didn't try it in conjunction with evicting.  If you post this as an answer I'll accept it.  Thank you so much for continuing to come back here and add comments to help me through it!

Comment: done. Glad I've been of some help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, it seems there are two points to consider to ensure thread safety, as well a non conflicting sessions :

- calling Session.Evict(_configStub1) once your object has been handled by the session. 
  This way you prevent non Garbage-Collected Sessions from generating conflicting interactions with your object.
- lock your object before it is attached to a session, and until it has been evicted from this session. This way, you ensure thread safety on your object.

Answer (score 0):

Interacting with an entity object currently active in a session (i.e. known by the session) should be regarded the same as interacting with the session. Since the session is not safe for concurrent use from different threads, neither is access to entity objects known by the session.

This is because interacting with an entity instance may cause the session to lazy load some data, and during the call to Save() (or similar methods) NHibernate will mutate the object to set the id (depending on the choosen identity assignment strategy).

The above applies in the general case. In more narrow scenarios it might be possible to do it safely, but I would argue that you should be really sure you need such a thing before you introduce that complexity.

Comment: I'd really have to do a pretty lengthy workaround (e.g. factories, passing around context types, etc.) as my option.  So, I am interested in your last paragraph "...it might be possible to do it safely"  <-- this is what I am after, that is where I am stuck and can't see beyond.  How can I do that?

Comment: I don't understand what you hope to gain by having multiple threads modify the same object concurrently. Regarding pessimistic locking, you can use that to ensure only one session/transaction at a time can operate on a particular row in the database (each session would have their own instance of the entity object).

Comment: By "... it might be possible ..." I meant that if you carefully design your domain model and you NHibernate configuration and likely using locks in the domain model, then perhaps you can ensure that calls to the domain model will never trigger the session to do something. But this sounds really brittle.